# Unable to get the resolved attributes within custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have been trying to write a custom directive for an input field with dynamic id, in the directive am unable to get the correct id.

```
<input id="myInput{{$index}}" my-dir="fn()"/>

myApp.directive('myDir', function ($parse) {
    var obj = {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: {
            post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var fn = $parse(attrs.myDir);
                var elementId = element.attr('id');
                console.log(elementId); // Here I see myInput{{$index}} instead of myInput0, by this time angular is not resolving the value         
            }
        }
    };
    return obj;
});
```

My question would be, how can I get the resolved value in the directive. Also I cannot use any isolated scope here due to other reasons.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [$observe](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#attributes) to observe the value changes of attributes that contain ***interpolation*** (e.g. src="{{bar}}"). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because **during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to undefined**.

```
post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('id', function (id) {
        console.log(id)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to evaluate the value once in the link function, you can use $interpolate (remember to inject it into your directive):

```
console.log($interpolate(element.attr('id'))(scope));
```

However, since you are likely using ng-repeat (because of the use of `$index`) I prefer @sza's answer, since your list may change, hence you may need to react to changes to your list.