# Run a function when variables are loaded

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

I have an NgComponent that is supposed to load data from another file based on a parameter in the tag. Here is an example tag:

```
<line-graph width="800" height="250" src="table.csv" />
```

If I attempt to load data based on the src variable in the constructor, it is null. I know that the value is being set, just at a later time. Is there a way to call the load function when the element is full initialized and the variables have been loaded from that DOM?

Comment: I have found the solution. Make the NgComponent implement NgAttachAware. You can then call the necessary code from inside the attach function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496603/unable-to-get-the-resolved-attributes-within-custom-directive You can use $observe to observe the value changes of attributes that contain interpolation (e.g. src="{{bar}}"). Not only is this very efficient but it's also the only way to easily get the actual value because during the linking phase the interpolation hasn't been evaluated yet and so the value is at this time set to undefined.

post: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    attrs.$observe('id', function (id) {
        console.log(id)
    })
}

Comment: $observe and $watch are IMHO not the best attempts. You can just make the field a setter and the code in the setter get's executed every time the value is set.

Answer (score 1):

implement `NgAttachAware` and run your code in `attach()`.
I read about a bug that even this is not working with some directives recently.
In this case try to run the code inside attach with `new Future(() { your code here });`

To make code execute every time the value is changed you can make `src` a setter and the code in the setter gets executed every time the value is changed.

```
String _src;
@NgTwoWay('src')
String get src => _src;
set src(String val) {
  _src = value;
  // your additional code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can accomplish this by using the `$watch` function.](https://docs.angulardart.org/#angular/angular.Scope@id_watch) The `$watch` function will be renamed to `watch` in the next version. Here is an example implementation:

```
class Component {

  @NgAttr("src")
  String src;

    Scope scope;
    Component(this.scope){
    scope.$watch(() => src, (value, previousValue){
      if (value == null) return;

      //load and draw data
    })
  }
}
```

In the next version it will look something like this:

```
class Component {

  @NgAttr("src")
  String src;

    Scope scope;
    Component(this.scope){
    scope.watch(src, (value, previousValue){
      if (value == null) return;

      //load and draw data
    })
  }
}
```